# Second conditional - "If we had any questions, would it be possible to discuss them with you in a meeting?"

Tags: conditionals

Is this question right?

> If we had any questions, would it be possible to discuss them with you in a meeting?

My "having questions" depends on a fact that will take place in the future.

Comment: If we **have** any questions, **will** it be possible to discuss them with you in a meeting?

Comment: Agree with @WeatherVane: your original question is perfectly good, but implication is that we are not expecting to have questions ("counterfactual"). Weather Vane's emendation implies that we may or may not have questions in the future.